# Why is custom ExpandableListView not displayed in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am trying to make custom `ExpandableListView` having child or node. But some parents don't have children. I don't want to show anything. In other words

I need to display like that

```
Parent 1
parent 2
  child1
  child2
  child3
parent 3
parent 4
  child1
```

So I try like this  I make a xml **route_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom adapter**

```
public class CustomExpendableListView extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private String[] fatherName={"naveen","ravi","sharma","uncle","rahat"};
    String[] raviChildrenname={"abc","pqr","mnn"};
    String[] sharmaChildrenname={"zxa","yh","er"};
    Context context;
    public CustomExpendableListView(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parenttextview, null);
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentTextView);
        item.setText(fatherName[groupPosition]);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

**call main function**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.route_dashboard);
    expendablelistView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    adapter = new CustomExpendableListView(this);
    expendablelistView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**parenttextviewxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parentTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I take three array

```
private String[] fatherName={"naveen","ravi","sharma","uncle","rahat"};
        String[] raviChildrenname={"abc","pqr","mnn"};
        String[] sharmaChildrenname={"zxa","yh","er"};
```

**fatherName** is the parents nodes.**raviChildrenname** is the child of **ravi** parent node .**sharmaChildrenname** is the child of **sharma**

could you please give some code.?

Comment: So your ExpListView is not displaying at all?

Comment: Your return statements in the adapter are allways 0 or null. For example at getChildCount or getGroupCount, You are returning 0, so this will not work. Also Your getChildView is returning null, so You will not get any child in the list. See here for a simple ExpandableListView example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/

Comment: Also maintain a Hashmap for mapping parent child relations That way you can see if parent does not have child you dont need to return 0 explicitly use a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> test` and in get childrencount return the size of array list for particular string mapped in the test `HashMap` also get child should not be null . Please see a simple example mentioned by @Opiatefuchs

Comment: could you please change some code...or change on my code

Comment: its your **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** in the list add weight to it if you use a linear layout or set it to **match_parent** together with @Sergey Pekar answer

Answer (score 1):

Your getGroupCount method must return value greater than zero. In this case only list view will display something
Something like that:

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return fatherName.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (fatherName[groupPosition].equalsIgnoreCase("ravi")) {
            return raviChildrenname.length;
    }

    if (fatherName[groupPosition].equalsIgnoreCase("sharma")) {
            return sharmaChildrenname.length;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You also need to implement getChildView method for this listView:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.childView, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);

     if (fatherName[groupPosition].equalsIgnoreCase("ravi")) {
            item.setText(raviChildrenname[childPosition]);
    }

    if (fatherName[groupPosition].equalsIgnoreCase("sharma")) {
            item.setText( sharmaChildrenname[childPosition]);
    }

    return item;
}
```